# Can I apply style to a view based on type of interface it inherits?

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance

I have a style declared in my resource dictionary.

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="800"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="600"/>
</Style>
```

I want the first style to apply to views who inherit from IDialogWindow, and second style to apply to views that inherit from IMainWindow.

Edit: The idea is to enforce style based on type of window throughout entire application.

Comment: And which style should it use when you have `partial class YourWindow : Window, IDialogWindow, IMainWindow`?

Comment: I would not be inheriting from `IDialogWindow` and `IMainWindow` on same class.

Comment: Ok, in that case can you use two abstract classes instead of interfaces derived from Window? If yes, this is easily done, if no this is quite hard (and I don't know off the top of my head how it could be done)